# Sorting list of strings that contain number with Python

Tags: python

I have list of strings that look like this:

```
l = ["sometext-2022-21_sometext", 
"sometext-2022-4_sometext", 
"sometext-2022-121_sometext",
"sometext-2022-321_sometext", 
"sometext-2022-1_sometext",
"sometext-2022-31_sometext"]
```

I want to sort it so that biggest number be on top, for example:

```
l = ["sometext-2022-321_sometext", 
"sometext-2022-121_sometext", 
"sometext-2022-31_sometext",
"sometext-2022-21_sometext", 
"sometext-2022-4_sometext",
"sometext-2022-1_sometext"]
```

How can I do that, since sort does not work for this problem?
PS
In this case the string with biggest number is longest, but that does not have to be the case, strings can have different texts.

This is my real list of strings:

```
["https://essgfsgffghe.ch/docs/BS_Omni/BS_APG_001_AUS-2022-401_nodate.html", 
"https://ensfgtsfgscheidsuche.ch/docs/BS_Omni/BS_APG_001_BEZ-2022-39_nodate.html", 
"https://ensfgtsfguche.ch/docs/BS_Omni/BS_APG_001_VD-2022-5_nodate.html", 
"https://egsfsfgtscheidsuche.ch/docs/BS_Omni/BS_APG_001_VD-2022-2_nodate.html", 
"https://ensfgidsuche.ch/docs/BS_Omni/BS_APG_001_BES-2022-83_nodate.html", 
"https://sfgfgnsfgche.ch/docs/BS_Omni/BS_SVG_001_IV-2022-54_nodate.html", 
"https://entscsfghe.ch/docs/BS_Omni/BS_APG_001_BES-2022-36_nodate.html", 
"https://essntscsfguche.ch/docs/BS_Omni/BS_APG_001_AUS-2022-32_nodate.html", 
"https://entsfgeidsuche.ch/docs/BS_Omni/BS_APG_001_BES-2022-89_nodate.html", 
"https://entfsfgsgsfuche.ch/docs/BS_Omni/BS_APG_001_AUS-2022-412_nodate.html", 
"https://ensfgche.ch/docs/BS_Omni/BS_APG_001_VD-2022-5_nodate.html", 
"https://ensfgse.ch/docs/BS_Omni/BS_APG_001_BES-2022-70_nodate.html", 
"https://esfgche.ch/docs/BS_Omni/BS_APG_001_VD-2022-1_nodate.html"]
```

Comment: will it always be 2022-###, or will it sometimes be 2021 or 2023? and if it is different, do we want 2023s at the top, or just sort by the ###?

Comment: You might be able to use a regex to pull out the number. That first "sometext", can it contain dashes (-)? Or can we assume that the first dash followed by a digit is your number?

Comment: it can be any 4 digit number - any 1 to 4 digit number

Comment: sometext can have a lot of - and _ and /

Comment: If sometext can contain, say, "-2021-11_" then we can't tell it apart from the real "-2022-321_" that you want to sort on.

Comment: no it can to contain that, you can treat it as a url that ends with numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to use a regular expression as long as the pattern searched is not also contained in "sometext", resulting in false positives. `list.sort` takes a function that returns a key to use for sorting instead of of the original value in the list. In this case, we can convert string digits to a tuple of integers that will sort the way you want.

```
import re

l = ["sometext-2022-21_sometext",
"sometext-2022-4_sometext",
"sometext-2022-121_sometext",
"sometext-2022-321_sometext",
"sometext-2022-1_sometext",
"sometext-2022-31_sometext"]

def l_sort_key(s):
    v1, v2 = re.search(r"-(\d+)-(\d+)_", s).groups()
    return int(v1), int(v2)
    
l.sort(key=l_sort_key, reverse=True)
print(l)
```

Comment: Your solution is good, but it does not work on my real example, I posted the real issue that I have, with real data, please take a look

Comment: The new data worked for me. You could reduce risk by stripping out the paths in the url: `v1, v2 = re.search(r"-(\d+)-(\d+)_", s.split('/')[-1]).groups()` but it doesn't seem necessary on the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted(iterable, key=func, reverse=True)` with the func defined to pull out the thing you actually want to sort by. In your case, could be something like this.

```
def sort_func(item):
    '''returns list of [2022, ###]'''
    vals = item.split('_')
    nums = vals[0].split('-')[1:3]
    nums = [int(num) for num in nums]
    return nums
    
sorted_list = sorted(l, key=sort_func, reverse=True)
```

If the way to identify the number in the middle is more complex, then you may indeed need a more robust regex solution